# undefined reference to symbol 'XF86VidModeQueryExtension' (linux, qt creator IDE)

Tags: c++, qt, g++, dynamic-linking, glfw

I've been trying to get some simple GL code that implements GFLW3 to compile on QT Creator (on Ubuntu 13.04). However I keep getting the same output when it tries building:

```
undefined reference to symbol 'XF86VidModeQueryExtension'
```

I then went to the .pro file and linked the lXxf86vm.so library file and added -lXxf86vm but it still gives the same output:

```
g++ -m64 -o GL-Test main.o windowtest.o frametest.o   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so 
-L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.a -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0 
-L/home/syk435/Testing\ Gl/GL-Test/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lXxf86vm -lX11 -lGL -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XF86VidModeQueryExtension'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'XF86VidModeQueryExtension' is defined in DSO /home/syk435/Testing Gl/GL-Test/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libXxf86vm.so 
so try adding it to the linker command line
/home/syk435/Testing Gl/GL-Test/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libXxf86vm.so:
could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

as you can see, I've tried four different ways to link the correct lib but it's still giving me the same "undefined reference" and "symbols could not be read" errors. Any insight on the proper way to link?

Edit: Pro file: TEMPLATE = app

```
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += x11

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += gl

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += glfw3

LIBS += -lXxf86vm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1
LIBS += -lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so
LIBS += -lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.a
LIBS += -lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: `-lXxf86vm` most likely should go after `-lglfw3` in the invocation of `gcc`. So change the order and see how it goes. If it's successful, then I can post it as an answer for you.

Comment: Have you re-run qmake explicitly, just in case? Also, you added those library names to the LIBS variable, right? Show the project file please. Also, these libraries are installed into the standard library location on your machine, right?

Comment: I've been suspecting that, but I've been having great difficulty make the .pro file switch order. Even when I write the lXxf86vm lib after all the others, it doesn't seem to change order Edit: shown above

Comment: Show your project file, please. Have you tried pkgconfig as well instead of LIBS?

Comment: That's because you're mixing `PKGCONFIG` with `LIBS`. Furthermore, you're using `-L` in a wrong way, i.e. it should be directory rather than file. Maybe you should put `CONFIG += link_pkgconfig` after `LIBS` (don't forget to fix `-L` too as well)?

Comment: Try to get rid of the mix of `PKGCONFIG` and `LIBS` - use either of them only, and keep `-lXxf86vm` at the end as I said. It should work.

Comment: Thanks once again! I had no idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
LIBS += -lXxf86vm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1
LIBS += -lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so
LIBS += -lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.a
LIBS += -lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
```

You are using the `-L` option with a file name rather than a path! You should change those four lines to:

```
LIBS += -lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Secondly, if the ordering matters, you would need to use `LIBS` for glfw3, too, something like this:

```
LIBS += -lglfw3 -lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Do not forget to assign the glfw3 path as well if needed. That is depending on your setup. You could probably try to swap the order of your current PKGCONFIG and LIBS statements, but it is not that much future proof if you move code around. Also, if you can share the path between the two libraries, I would not personally use PKGCONFIG, just LIBS.

Comment: I tried every variation of this as well as Haroogan's answer, but still the output is /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XF86VidModeQueryExtension'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'XF86VidModeQueryExtension' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libXxf86vm.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libXxf86vm.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation

Comment: well thank you very much for the answer, I did as you said regarding putting Libs += for glfw3 in order to change order, and the error went away. I now have same error with pthread, but I'm assuming by manipulating order and directly linking it should clear up.

Comment: @user1909464: add `-lpthread` to the LIBS line, and similar other libraries if needed like `-lm`, et al.